# Bind CheckListBox to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm using a CheckListBox from the WPF Toolkit and trying to bind it to my ViewModel.  In addition to obtaining the selected values from the control I would also like to be able to reset it through a button click which would clear any selections.  I'm stuck on how to bind the selected or checked state of each item in the collection, but if my whole approach is off I would appreciate some direction on that as well.

I've created a simple class with a string descriptor and a Boolean property that I planned to use to indicate the state of each checkbox...

```
public class DrugInfluence : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Impairment { get; set; }
    private bool isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if(isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

A collection of DrugInfluence objects in the ViewModel called ImpairmentList that I want to bind to the CheckListBox control iteself...

```
    public List<DrugInfluence> ImpairmentList
    {
        get
        {
            return impairmentList;
        }
        set
        {
            if(impairmentList != value)
            {
                impairmentList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ImpairmentList");
            }
        }            
    }
```

And the XAML I'm using to bind the ViewModel to the CheckListBox control...

```
        <sdk:CheckListBox Margin="6"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ImpairmentList}"   
                          DisplayMemberPath="Impairment"
                          SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked"
                          SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedImpairments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </sdk:CheckListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckListBox&referringTitle=Home) the control you are using?  If so, it looks like SelectedMemberPath is the property you want to bind to.  You will also need to raise an event when the IsChecked property changes if you want to check/uncheck programatically. For instance,

```
 public class DrugInfluence : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Impairment { get; set; }

        private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked 
        { 
            get{ return _isChecked;}
            set
            {
                if (_isChecked!= value)
                {
                    _isChecked= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }; 
        }
    }
```

And then implement the rest of the INotifyPropertyChanged members

Comment: Yes that's the control.  As for my approach, I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModel and not in the DrugInfluence class itself, I was thinking that I would try to bind SelectedMemberPath (as you suggested) to the IsChecked property for a collection of DrugInfluence objects in my ViewModel, and the raise event notification would be taken care of - am I way off on this?

Comment: You will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on DrugInfluence also.  The only thing that will be taken care of by the ObservableCollection is if the item source changes (i.e. is set to a new list, or an item is added/removed).  It will not automatically handle changes of the elements in the list.

Comment: By binding the IsChecked property to the SelectedMemberPath, you are telling WPF to listen for a change to that property.  You have to tell it that it has changed, and it will take care of updating the UI.

Comment: I've updated my code above, but I'm not able to programmatically clear the checkboxes by setting the IsChecked property = false when a button is clicked.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: IsChecked property is always false.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you remove the SelectedItemsOverride property from your xaml?

Comment: Ok that's the nudge I needed, I just have to use the IsChecked property to get the selected items out of the original collection.  Thanks again for all your help!